# Gender neutral photos for users who don't yet have a profile picture

Tags: user-research, user-expectation, profile

I am administering a web application that has male and female users.

Currently, the default user photo is:

[image]

I don't like this because it seems rather masculine and gives me the impression that the database has me recorded as a male.

I think changing the default to this makes sense:

[image]

This is more of a gender neutral avatar.

Questions:

- Would the first image be considered inconsiderate by a typical (female) user?
- Does the second image rectify the problem created by the first image?

Note that the application does not know whether the user is male or female and so having two separate default photos, one male and the other female, is not possible.

---

**Edit:** I have been asked to define the characteristics that make an avatar gender neutral. I am not sure I can do this objectively and that is why I choose to pick an avatar that has a very slight representation of a human head and shoulders. In other words, I prefer to solve the problem by not having a man-like or woman-like shadow at all.

Comment: I think u r right with the idea of using neutral face icon but ur image doesn't feel better.

Comment: Can you reword your question a bit to be more about what characteristics make an avatar gender neutral and/or alternative practices addressing this issue?  Right now this question feels pretty close to a site review/icon suggestion question, which is off topic.

Comment: An alternative quite a few sites use is a question mark icon instead of a silhouette.

Comment: @JoshuaBarron I have modified the question

Comment: @karancan I like the idea of gender neutral avatars, however, why did you use an [Asgardian](http://www.26horses.com/forum/images/user/avatars/avatar_11418_1394300551.jpg) avatar? Try making the next a bit wider and adding ears.

Comment: Consider an [identicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon), which StackExchange uses as its default. Has some pretty big advantages over a single stock image, depending on what sort of web app you have. (e.g. great for SE where pseudonymity is common and real-life identities are largely irrelevant, but a negative IMO for Facebook, where *everyone* should have their own real image)

Comment: Howsabout [this](http://cdn-2.brainden.com/images/family.gif)?

Comment: Your gender neutral avatar doesn't look like a person to me...it looks more like this guy: http://defensetech.org/2008/07/25/nasa-naut-claims-alien-coverup/

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Another alternative to consider is the initials of the user. This is done by the collaborative card site Trello, and many others.

So if your name was John Smith, you would see for example a gray square like you had for that first image, with the two centered letters 'JS'. A simple sans-serif and readable font like Helvetica would be great for that (you want readability to be a top priority for various sizes).

For example:

[image: Basic Avatar]

That would be the easiest catch-all solution. But to answer your two questions:

1. Quite possibly. If you (I'm assuming you're male) made an account on a website for social purposes, would you want your first avatar to be a female, with all your friends seeing it? Probably not. There are people who wouldn't care either way. **But there are enough that it's something to take into account.**
2. Yes, your second image would fix the issue of gender. However, the image itself would need some work, as it's not that visually appealing/engaging (that's another topic/question to ask here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The user initials is a great idea. It's used in a ton of places now e.g. Gmail. It makes it easier to distinguish between users who haven't uploaded their avatar.

Comment: iOS 7 also does that ! :)

Comment: May be worth taking a look at Gravatar as a fallback if they've not added their own photo? They offer all sorts of defaults including the geometry ones here.

Comment: I think your suggestion of using initials is a solid approach. However, you seem to be asserting that men would mind being represented as a female avatar, but that women *wouldn't* mind the reverse. Is this what you actually want to convey? If not, I suggest rephrasing your first point.

Comment: @PhilCalvin That's not quite what I was trying to convey. Thank you for pointing that out, the original post has been edited to be more general.

Comment: I don't think it's a appropriate to use a gravatar based on email address unless you're also displaying the email address. Gravatar reveals information about email addresses that users might have expected to be kept private.

Comment: @bdsl, what kind of information is displayed based off a gravatar? My understanding is that gravatar images (which by default are just geometric patterns) are meant to be public anyway, so that you have a single place to manage your online profile picture across multiple sites.

Comment: @Andrew The fact that it's a single picture across multiple sites displays the information that it's the same person on on two sites, while they may have been trying to keep that identity secret. Maybe on one site they mention where they work and on another site they mention a controversial opinion.

Using gravatar normally means publishing a hash of the user email address.

Comment: Fair enough. However, Gravatar is used regularly across many sites, and it may be appropriate depending on the situation (if we're talking social network, sure, business, maybe not). So the recommendation of using Gravatar as a fallback could still be valid. But you are right, you need to know the situation in which this applies to make sure that it would be appropriate.

Answer (score 17):

You can certainly objectively define the characteristics that would make an avatar male or female. Take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_sex_characteristic (there are other lists that might work better, but this one was easy to find; cultural aspects of "gender display" should also be considered)

There are some characteristics that would be visible in a outline based avatar. In your example, the heavier bone structure of the skull is apparent, as is overall squareness (as well as the cultural bias of short hair). To define an avatar as neutral it should have no aspects of "gender display".

As to your specific questions:

1. No idea, and I would venture to say no one does. You would need to ask your female users to learn this lesson. However if you can avoid the problem of gender all together you probably should. Lets not forget about Facebook's ever growing list of identities, do you really want to address these issues?
2. The second image does have near zero secondary sexual characteristics. But it does have some feminine traits, like a rounder skull structure, and thinner neck.

I did a quick search on the noun project for "user": http://thenounproject.com/search/?q=user These seem to be the most non-gendered to me personally:

[image] [image]

However you could just use text that also informs as to the state of the system, for example:

### No Photo Uploaded

As long as area that will contain an avatar image, is clear as to its intent as a avatar image, you should be fine with an avoidance of the gender issue. You could even follow Gravatar's lead and use a pattern:

[image]

Comment: That's not Stack Exchange's lead. That's gravatar's lead. For example, mine is https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/eba3df62ea97ea9065ca70e9c06b80aa?d=identicon

Comment: Why not use [unicorns](http://unicornify.appspot.com/)! They should be gender-neutral enough. [Example](http://unicornify.appspot.com/avatar/ba95799ceedd18316033196cb243cfc0?s=128)

Comment: @corsiKa updated.

Comment: @SztupY that would be fine, it just not likely going to get by marketing, or marry well with their branding (not to many companies with unicorns in the design spec)

Comment: Neither of the images in your bullet points work. They both give us access denied errors. Please upload those images to Stack Exchange hosting, rather than hotlinking off another site. That has the added benefit that we don't have to worry about those images disappearing next week whenever those hosts don't need them any longer.

Comment: Why not just use gravatar, then they will get their existing avatar?

Comment: @JamesRyan Gravatar is an interesting idea. But it would ultimately depend on the application being developed. To my knowledge, gravatar uses the same avatar despite which site it's on. A facebook or twitter avatar might not be appropriate for a site like LinkedIn (for example). Good thought though.

Comment: I like the idea of throwing away the problem of gender all together. One could just remove any gender-related stuff and call everybody "they" by default.

Comment: @Andrew This is a problem that mostly solves itself naturally.  People tend to use different email addresses for work or personal use, although true that is not universal.

Comment: I don't know whether the unicorn comment was a joke or serious, but on Google drive, anonymous users are given animals as avatars. So something gender neutral can be something non-human entirely!

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I think is a relatively genderless profile image:

[image: genderless profile photo]

Comment: Hi Nicholas, please try to answer the questions from the original poster.

Comment: Welcome to [ux.se]! Please have a look at the Help Center article [answer].